# Get input value from ID form

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the input value from a form. I have differents forms with differents IDs, but the input names are the same, so I need to take the correct value from the correct form.

I tried to take with the select $('form'+id).find(('input[name=epiDesc]') but doesn't work. The id is a variable that I take it from the click event of a button.

```
      var desc6=$('input[name="desc6"]');
      desc6.keyup(function(){

      var padre=$(this).parents('tr');
      var epiDesc=padre.find('input[name="epiDesc"]');
      epiDesc.val($(this).val());
      console.log(padre.attr('id'));
            });
     $('.btn-success').click(function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
              var id= $(this).attr('id');

              $('form#'+id).find('input[name=epiDesc]').val();
};
```

**HTML**

```
             @foreach ($datos as $item)
                      <form id="{{$item['id']}}">
                        <tr id="{{$item['id']}}">

                        <td class="fixed-column">{{$item['id']}}</td>

                        <td><input type="text" name="epiDesc" readonly ></td>
                        <td> <input type="text" name="desc5" value="{{$item['desc5']}}" placeholder="{{$item['desc5']}}" readonly></iput>
                        <input type="text" name="epi5" hidden value="{{$item['epi5']}}"</input>
                       </td>
                       <td><input type="text" name="desc6" placeholder="{{$item['desc']}}" required></input></td>
                       <td><button type="sumbit" class="btn btn-success" id="{{$item['id']}}">Guardar</button></td>
                   </tr>
                   </form>
             @endforeach
```

This is a part of my html. The value of the input(name=epiDesc) is entered when the keyup function is activated. I'm sure that this input it's ok.

Any idea to take the correct value from the different forms when I click the button??
thanks

Comment: Add your html also.

Comment: Your jQuery snippet is incomplete

Comment: you are getting id of the clicked element and then using the same id to get form... confusing... is there any duplicate id?

Comment: Can you also share **HTML**. Thanks

Comment: I added the htlm, it's a very long form, I hope I was correct at the summary

Comment: I solved => `$('tr#'+id).children('td').find('input[name=epiDesc]')` . It's easier on that way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$('form#'+id).find('input[name=epiDesc]').val();
```